# Scrolling effect for GUI menu in BGE

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, logic-bricks

So I'm making a GUI for my first person shooter type of game and I'm having trouble with making the effect for scrolling through the icons, trying to select one at a time instead of all. I basically have no idea how to do it so my question is, does anyone know how to use the mouse to scroll through the icons instead of selecting them all? I know why it selects them all I just want to know how to select them one at a time using the mouse wheel to go up and down the icons.

Here's a link to what I'm trying to make overall (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALGcJVFb5oo)
but as or right now I just need help getting the icon selection part right.

You can check out the blend file here-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0312glj761zaei/SAO%20Ui.blend?dl=0

The only controls I have so far is when you press <kbd>E</kbd> it brings down the menu and when you use the wheel on the mouse it selects the icon (which is what I'm having trouble with...)

Comment: you are activating them all at the same time

Comment: I realize that its just the problem is how do i select them one at a time

Comment: one send message to the next to get active , or you'll have to do some scripting

Comment: any suggestions on how to start either of those

Comment: OK incrementing a property would be better , I'll try...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a property to hold the selected circle index, then switch between them each time the mouse-wheel rotate.

the easiest way was the script, the script is attached to the first circle as follows :

[image]

the first circle has two properties ***selected*** "the index of the selected circle"  and ***open***  "indicates whether the menu is open or not"

[image]

here is the script used in the file :

```
def switch_selected():
    #get this controller   
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    # the object running the script "1st cicle selected"
    owner = cont.owner
    # get this scene and a list of its objects
    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
    objects = scene.objects

    #hide all circles  to clear the previous selection ( also in case the menu is closed no circle is selected)
    objects['1st cicle selected'].visible = False
    objects['2nd Circle Selected'].visible = False
    objects['3d cicle Selected'].visible = False
    objects['4th Circle Selected'].visible = False
    objects['5th cicle Selected'].visible = False        

    #check if menu is open
    if owner['open'] :
        #get the mouse wheel sensors 
        mouse_up = cont.sensors["up"]
        mouse_down = cont.sensors["down"]

        #if mouse up increment index
        if mouse_down.positive :
            owner['selected'] += 1
            if owner['selected'] > 4 :
                owner['selected'] = 0
        #if mouse down decrement index
        if mouse_up.positive :
            owner['selected'] -= 1
            if owner['selected'] < 0 :
                owner['selected'] = 4   

        # read the index and set the selected to be visible
        selected = owner['selected']       
        if selected == 0 :
            objects['1st cicle selected'].visible = True
        elif selected == 1 :
            objects['2nd Circle Selected'].visible = True
        elif selected == 2 :
            objects['3d cicle Selected'].visible = True
        elif selected == 3 :
            objects['4th Circle Selected'].visible = True
        elif selected == 4 :
            objects['5th cicle Selected'].visible = True


switch_selected() #a call for the above function at each tick
```

Here is the file [image]

[image]

Comment: Dude thank you soooo much!! I couldn't get this figured out for days!! Thanks you

Comment: @CloudyCastle71 you are welcome, and if you see that this solve your problem mark the answer as accepted ( the check mark on the left )